# GoogleMaps "Sorry, we have no imagery here" in InternetExplorer 11

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-11

We're using google maps to display company locations on a map. It still works in Chrome, Firefox & Safari currently, however in IE 11 today we noticed that none of the tiles are loading and we get grey tiles with a text saying "Sorry, we have no imagery here". I checked the network tab and it looks like, the tile requests are trying to fetch the tiles from the domain, where the map is displayed instead of fetching them from the google servers.

I tried changing the version parameter to `v=weekly` and `v=3.3.6`, but it still behaves the same.

The map is embedded like this:
`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={API_KEY}&v=3.exp" defer></script>`

in IE11 the tile request looks like this:

`https://example.com/google-maps-page/undefinedpb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i34!3i21!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i480189574!3m14!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!12m4!1e26!2m2!1sstyles!2zcy50OjJ8cy5lOmx8cC52Om9mZg!4e0&key={API_KEY}&token={TOKEN}`

in chrome the working tile-requests look like this:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i31!3i22!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i480189574!3m14!2sde-DE!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!12m4!1e26!2m2!1sstyles!2zcy50OjJ8cy5lOmx8cC52Om9mZg!4e0!5m1!5f2&key={API_KEY}&token={TOKEN}`

Comment: IE11 works for me on a random example from the documentation.  ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ko4xvy17/), IE not supported, but displays map in "readonly" mode).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: It also works well on my side (using IE 11.116.18362.0 version), please check your code, whether you set the max map zoom level, if set it, try to change it. You could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527211/avoiding-sorry-we-have-no-imagery-here-with-google-maps). If still not working, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are also encountering the same problem.
Switching to `v=3.36` solves this for now, but 3.36 will be removed next update, where it will default to the "v=quarterly" response.

Comment: thank you.. i just realized that i put in `v=3.3.6` but it has to be `v=3.36` it works for me now. not sure how the long term fix will be though. i opened an issue here as well: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139888746

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my site is using `es6-shims` library, but once I change it to `core-js` library, google maps 3.38 works well in IE11, not sure if it is a google maps issue or `es6-shims` issue.

Without any shims google maps 3.38 does work in IE11, so the issue could be incompatibility between es6-shims and latest google maps